# vaadin :how to enable a field in the attachfield method?

Tags: vaadin, valuechangelistener

I have a Vaadin Form and I override the attachField method. Now let's say I have a checkBox, a textfield and another TextField and I only want the textField to be enabled when the checkbox is true.

I store the 2 textfield in a Group class:

```
package be.certipost.as2.gui.components.detail.custom;
```

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.vaadin.ui.Field;

public class Group {

```
private String id;
private Map<String, Field> fields;

public Group(String groupsId){
    this.id=groupsId;
    fields = new HashMap<String,Field>();
}

public Field findFieldById(String fieldId){
    System.out.println(fields.size());
    for( Map.Entry<String, Field> f: fields.entrySet()){
        if(f.getKey().equals(fieldId)){
            return f.getValue();
        }

    }

    return null;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled){
    for( Map.Entry<String, Field> f: fields.entrySet()){
        f.getValue().setEnabled(enabled);
    }
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void addField(String fieldId, Field field) {
    fields.put(fieldId,field);
    System.out.println(fields.size());

}
```

}

Now in the form I have a List groups..

For the checkbox I say that when It's clicked it will check the list of groups for the correct group and in that group i'll find the correct field. Then i set this field enabled/disabled... At compile level this works, but when I click the checkbox i get a nullpointerexception for the field.
So my group has zero fields at the point that i click the checkbox

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set the checkbox field as immediate

```
final Form form = new Form();
form.addItemProperty("checkbox", new ObjectProperty<Boolean>(Boolean.FALSE));
form.addItemProperty("txt1", new ObjectProperty<String>(""));
form.addItemProperty("txt2", new ObjectProperty<String>(""));
form.getField("txt1").setEnabled(Boolean.FALSE);
AbstractField field = (AbstractField) form.getField("checkbox");
field.setImmediate(true);
field.addListener(new ValueChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        form.getField("txt1").setEnabled((Boolean) event.getProperty().getValue());
    }
});
```